# What can i use to make an app like notes app where there is unexpected number of notes

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to make a notes apo in flutter but i dont know that widget can i use to store the notes as the number of notes are unexpected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ListView.builder` or `GridView.builder`, just specify the number of items in the `itemCount` field.

### Example using `GridView.builder`:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> notes = ["Lorem", "Ipsum", "Dolor"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: notes.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(notes[index]),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result:
[image: Example]

Comment: Sorry i was out of the city so was not able to reply...As in a notes app i dont know how much notes the user wants to add so in that case what will be the itemCount bound....

Comment: You can use a stateful widget, just add an "Add" button and on its `onPressed()` just add a new item to the `notes` list. Just dont forget to call `setState()` after you change your `notes` list.